# What's the most convenient way to analyze a sentence phrases and structure using NLTK or SpaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

[image]

What's the most convenient way to analyze a sentence phrases and structure using NLTK or SpaCy?
The main goal is to get a well organized and clean data in order to apply some inferential statistics on it.

Here is a simple example of what I need, as shown in the tree above:

NP which is a Noun Phrase

VP, a Verb Phrase

ADJP, Adjective Phrase

-, a coordinating conjunction, implying that it is a compound sentence

PP, a Prepositional Phrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient way is to use dependency parsing from spacy. https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#dependency-parse
From its output you can extract whatever information you need.
It is important to memorize that no parser will ever have perfect accuracy, so best choose a large model to guarantee good quality.